# Include library from github

Tags: android, eclipse

How to include this library https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop to my existing android project? 
Tried to import it via "Existing Projects into Workspace" and "File System" but I was unable to use the classes of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project is designed to be built by Gradle (and, by extension, Android Studio). The directory structure of the `lib/` project is not set up in the legacy project structure used by Eclipse or Ant.

You would have to create your own Android library project, then:

- Copy over [the manifest](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/master/lib/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) into your library project
- Copy over [the `res/` directory](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/tree/master/lib/src/main/res) into your library project
- Copy over [the `java/` directory](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/tree/master/lib/src/main/java) into your library project **as the `src/` directory in your project**

Then, in principle, you should be able to add your own edition of the library project to your app.